# UISegmented Control hides below the UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `firstViewController` which has a `UISegmentedControl` and `SegmentedControl` has two tabs button. its all working fine but when i go to next `SecondViewController`. On `SecondViewController` there is a link for `webView` when i push to that `webView` & then back to `SecondViewController` and then back to `firstViewController` by tapping back button. The `SegmentedControl` leave its position & it moves below the `NavigationController`

`firstViewController` Code is :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupMenuBar()
    setupViewControllerUI()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    setupNavigationBarUI()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // to avoid getting a black navigationBar while transition
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIColor.white.convertImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

    navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.appThemeRegularFontWithSize(20.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray]
}

// MARK: - UIViewController Helper Method

func setupViewControllerUI() {

    if isFirstVC {
        AppUtility.switchToViewController(viewController: firstViewController!, in: self)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    } else {
        LoadingViewController.sharedLoader.showLoading(self.navigationController!)
        AppUtility.switchToViewController(viewController: secondViewController, in: self)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    }
}

func setupMenuBar() {
    SegmentedControlContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.ButtonColorWithAlpha(1.0)
    segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
}

func setupNavigationBarUI() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.ButtonColorWithAlpha(1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIColor.ButtonColorWithAlpha(1.0).convertImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0).convertImage()
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.ButtonColorWithAlpha(1.0)
    segmentedControl.setTitle("first", forSegmentAt: 1)
    segmentedControl.setTitle("second", forSegmentAt: 0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    self.title = "Screen Name"

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: Have you used autolayout to layout segented control?

Comment: yes i use autoLayout its working fine but when i go back from webView then this issue is produced

Comment: If you have used Autolayout and segmentedcontrol top is set with respect to TopLayoutGuide, this issue should not arise.

Comment: segmentedControll should appear at the end of UINavigationController but its hide below the UINavigationController.

Comment: Can you share the code (the proj) so that we can help

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta i share my code

Comment: Share your xcode project. I believe the main issue is in the storyboard. Upload on google drive and share the link here.

Comment: i don't use storyboard i use xib